# Were Harmony Shoal in The Husbands of River Song?

Tags: doctor-who

Harmony Shoal and their zip heads look suspiciously like the followers of King Hydroflax.

**Has it been stated that they were related or the same species?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly. In [The Husbands of River Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Husbands_of_River_Song) they were referred to as the

> *Shoal of the Winter Harmony*

---

Given their extreme similarity and almost identical name it would be highly unusual if they weren't connected, especially given that Steven Moffat was at pains to confirm that the baddies were

> *"Not quite new. Fairly new. They’ve been around before. Something we’ve
> seen before but quite recently"*
>
> <sub><sup>[Steven Moffat reveals (almost) all about the Doctor Who Christmas special](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2016-12-07/steven-moffat-reveals-almost-all-about-the-doctor-who-christmas-special)</sup></sub>